# Calculate Color Between 2 RGB Values Based on Int Value Between 0-500

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, so if it is, good, if not, maybe I can be directed to the right place?
Anyway, I am trying to take 2 user inputs that are RGB values in tuple form.  Then, given an integer value between 0 and 500, I want to calculate an in-between RGB tuple.  So, a much lower integer value would lead to an RGB tuple that is closer to the FIRST user-given RGB tuple, and a higher integer value would lead to a tuple closer to the SECOND user-given RGB tuple.  That is, I want a final RGB tuple that falls somewhere in between the two user-given RGB tuples that varies based on the integer value in the 0-500 range.  I CANNOT, however, seem to get my mind around the math/logic necessary to make this work! If this is the wrong place to ask, I apologize.  Otherwise, thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a modified weighted average formula

Comment: Perhaps [python-colormath](https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can help you.

Answer (score 4):

One simplistic approach is to find a point in RGB-space on a line between the first and second color.

Simplifying even further, for each of the color components, find a value that is partway between them, at a distance proportional to the value the user specified.

For example, if the user specifies 125, then the distance is 1/4 (125/500). If the first value is 1 and the second value is 100, then 25 is 1/4 of the way from 1 to 100.

```
first_color = (1,10,240)
second_color = (100, 100, 200)

distance = 125  # Out of 500

result_color = tuple(int(c1 + distance * (c2-c1)/500.)
                     for c1, c2 in zip(first_color, second_color))
print(result_color)
```

Result:

```
$ python x.py 
(25, 32, 230)
```

This will always give a result; whether the chosen colors appear correct is another matter.